Controlled Z gate having no effect
Consider a quantum circuit with 2 qubits, q1 and q2.
If we apply the Hadamard to both and apply a controlled z between them, my expectation is that the phase would flip for |11> (like (|00⟩ + |01⟩ + |10⟩ - |11⟩)) and then when we apply the Hadamard again, that phase shift would carry into a negated amplitude in the computational basis for that state, decreasing the probability of measuring |11>.
However, when I run the following circuit in Qiskit, that's not what I'm seeing at all.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

N = 2
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(N)
qc1.h(range(N))
qc1.cz(0,1)
qc1.h(range(N))

# Step 4: Measure the qubits
qc1.measure_all()

# Execute the circuit using AerSimulator
simulator = AerSimulator()
# Transpile the circuit for the simulator
tqc = transpile(qc1, simulator)
# Run the circuit on the simulator
result = simulator.run(tqc).result()
# Get the measurement counts
counts = result.get_counts()

# Display results
print("Measurement Results:", counts)
qc1.draw('mpl')

gives me this circuit:

but I get these results:
Measurement Results: {'01': 248, '11': 249, '10': 266, '00': 261}
So, all states are measuring with basically equal probability, as if the phase shift had no effect. What am I not understanding?
